# Prevent JSON string to typescript interface getting extra properties

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm working on an Arduino extensions on VSCode and I got a problem with a part of my code.
I'm loading project's configuration from a `.json` file stored in the `.vscode` folder. Althought the user shouldn't edit this file manually, he may add values I don't want to see in the file.

I create an interface called `Config` and I get my configuration like this:

```js
interface Config {
    port?: string,
    baud?: number,
    board?: string
}

let myConfig: Config = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(`path/to/my/config.json`).toString());
```

For example I have this config:

```json
{ "test": "hi!" }
```

Even if `myConfig` is `Config`-typed, when I load my config and do a `console.log` of it, I see:

```
{test: 'hi!'}
```

I also test with to change `Config` to a class and a type but I can't prevent my config to extra unexpected properties. Is there a way to detect safty or with a `try {} catch {}` if a variable doesn't match with it's interface's structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. In TypeScript interfaces are a compile-time only model.

Also, don't use `as` to assert the type of an object to a class type, because if that object has not been initialized through the class constructor, that object is not an instance of that class; they don't have the same prototype.

What you can do is

- implementing a user-defined type guard
- manually creating an object with the desired properties from the object returned by JSON.parse
- ignore the extra fields on that object